# Происхождение слова "молодец"

Tags: этимология

В римской системе "М" - тысяча, "L" - пятьдесят, "D" - пятьсот, "С" - сто. Получается, все согласные этого слова являются римскими цифрами, которые могли использоваться для расчётов на бумаге или как обозначения рядов на счётах. Вопрос, совпадение это или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Совпадение. Молодец - это молодой человек, ср. *глупый-глупец, старый-старец*. С римскими цифрами это никак не связано.

Answer (score 1):

Совпали буквы алфавитов, не более. Не совпадает с действительностью отождествление  указанных знаков и букв. Знаки лишь выглядят, как (только КАПИТАЛЬНЫЕ!) буквы латиницы, однако графемы цифрового ряда имеют в основе — кроме единичных штрихов — два составленных под углом штриха (галочку). В тысяче (М) их два, а в у пятисот (D) фигура замкнута третьим, вертикальным.

Достаточно записать оба слова строчными буквами, связь русского слова и с римским цифровым алфавитом, и латиницей исчезнет.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же, этимология русского слова "молодец" никак не может быть основана на римских цифрах, появившихся за два тысячелетия до возникновения самого русского языка. Поэтому какаяя-либо причинно-следсьвенная связь просто исключена. 
Другое дело, что кто-то мог воспользоваться словом "молодец" для запоминания набора букв, используемых как римские цифры (причем не всех, X и V туда не попали).

Что же касается самих цифровых значений этих букв, то есть несколько взаимоисключающих версий, непонятно даже что было первично: сами или они просто заменили какие-то чем-то похожие на них знаки (например V - может быть знаком ладони, "пятерни", X - двух ладоней, D - половинкой от кружка-тысячи и так далее). Но ни одна из версий не предполагает какого-либо  предопределенного латинского слова, эти буквы содержащего. Странно было бы предполагать, что в русском языке такое слово вдруг появилось.

Comment: В переводе на латинский сто - это **c**entum, половина - **d**imidium, тысяча - **m**ille. Так что этимология C, D, M не представляет особых проблем.

Comment: @МаркИз В отношении С и М я ничего не говорил, а вот D  от dimedium представляется несколько натянутым. В нашем разговоре - не принципиально, все равно полной картины нет.

Comment: Если появление этих цифр и их буквенного обозначения предшествовало появлению слова, то это скорее аргумент за причинно-следственную связь чем против. 
Можно предположить что было что-то вроде счёт где ряды костяшек были обозначены этими символами и эти счёты "пришли" до возникновения слова.

Comment: *Можно предположить что было что-то вроде счёт* - да это-то можно предположить (хотя и не фиксируется), но как это стало причиной появления слова?!

Comment: https://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fs4erbinin.ru%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F05%2FOBS05.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fs4erbinin.ru%2Fmath%2Fmultiply&docid=q34kUFY_gfNZ4M&tbnid=S1owSSB6xECeKM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiN0IvcwPDTAhWGCJoKHdB3AoM49AMQMwgPKA0wDQ..i&w=325&h=231&bih=950&biw=1920&q=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA&ved=0ahUKEwiN0IvcwPDTAhWGCJoKHdB3AoM49AMQMwgPKA0wDQ&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: Применялся пятеричный счёт с уровнями MDCL находящимися очень близко друг к другу. Когда на языке и перед глазами "крутятся" буквы или совершается мнемоническая операция это же может привести к появлению слова?